# Coprime factorization of rational matrix over the polynomial ring

Tags: polynomials, rational-functions, coprime

Dear esteemed colleagues,

I have a question regarding the coprime factorization of rational matrices over the polynomial ring. Consider the following rational matrix

$$
R(s) = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{s+1} \\ \frac{1}{s+1} \end{pmatrix},
$$

for which I know a right coprime factorization over the polynomial ring, i.e., $R(s) = N_r(s) D_r^{-1} (s) =  \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} (s+1)^{-1}$. However, I'm interested in a left coprime factorization, i.e., $R(s) = D_\ell^{-1} (s) N_\ell(s)  $. I have found the following factorization

$$
 D_\ell = (s+1) I_2, \quad \quad N_\ell = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix},
$$

but it is unfortunately not coprime.

Does there exist a leftcoprime factorization over the polynomial ring for this example?
Does a left AND right coprime factorization over the polynomial ring always exist for general non-square rational matrices?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Smith-McMillan from will lead to a left coprime factorization, but by observation, we could have
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
s+1&s+1\\
1&-1
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}2\\0
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{s+1}\\\frac{1}{s+1}
\end{bmatrix}
$$